# A more simple approach to  role-based access control (RBAC)?

Tags: php, rbac

I'm having a difficult time grasping the code behind role-based access control (RBAC). I'm trying to use a "bundle" with the Laravel framework but it only seems to be complicating things more.

What I need for my specific application is three roles. The first and most basic role is just to allow users to be able log into my application, manage their account, and save "favorites" and "deals". The second role I need is to allow store owners to be able to log in and create accounts and deals. The third role is basically an admin role so I can go in and remove unwanted content if need be.

Would there be any anticipated problems with just simply adding an int field to the user table called something like "role"? If a user's role is 0, then they have basic privileges and can't access the admin and owner area of the site; a 1 would indicate the user has an owner role, etc. I would simply check the user's role every time a request was made.

Would this be a reasonable, secure solution, or could I potentially run into problems using this approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using RBAC would give you more flexibility when it comes to managing access to your application's functionality. Each user can be assigned with multiple roles, tasks and operations; each role can consist of multiple tasks and each tasks can consist of multiple operations.

If your application only demands 3 roles, basic, owner and admin, I think it's fine to just add an indicator in your user table. However, if you need to grant certain users access to certain operations, you would need a new number for every operation you want to differentiate access controls. Hence, using that approach would make it difficult to separate permissions based on functionality.

An alternative solution is to use ACL, which I believe it's easier to implement but probably a bit more difficult to manage. You can learn the difference between ACL and RBAC [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/346/what-is-the-difference-between-rbac-and-dac-acl).